# Piecewise SHA1 does not match SHA1 in one go

Tags: c++, openssl, sha1

I have a function to compute the hash of an URL:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <string>
void url_hash(
    std::string const& scheme,
    std::string const& userinfo,
    std::string const& host,
    std::string const& domain,
    std::string const& port,
    std::string const& path,
    std::string const& query,
    std::string      & url_hash)
{
    std::string key(scheme + userinfo + host + domain + port + path + query);

    char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA1((const unsigned char*)(key.data()), key.size(), (unsigned char*)digest);
    url_hash = base64::encode(digest + 0, digest + SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
}
```

This works correctly, verified with 'openssl sha1' and www.sha1-online.com

I thought, let's avoid creating the copy; we can do SHA1 on pieces.

```
void url_hash(
    std::string const& scheme,
    std::string const& userinfo,
    std::string const& host,
    std::string const& domain,
    std::string const& port,
    std::string const& path,
    std::string const& query,
    std::string      & url_hash)
{
#define SHA_IT(s) SHA1_Update(&ctx, s.data(), s.size())
    char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH]; // SHA1 is fixed size, 160 bits

    SHA_CTX    ctx;
    SHA1_Init(&ctx);

    SHA_IT(scheme);
    SHA_IT(userinfo);
    SHA_IT(host);
    SHA_IT(domain);
    SHA_IT(port);
    SHA_IT(path);
    SHA_IT(query);
    SHA_Final((unsigned char*)&digest, &ctx);

    url_hash = base64::encode(digest + 0, digest + SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
#undef SHA_IT
}
```

Unfortunately, the digest calculated this way does not match the digest calculated in one go :(

I must be doing something wrong but I can't see what it is.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but if you're going to `#define` a macro within a function, you should probably `#undef` it before the end.

Comment: This could mess up subsequent functions (luckily there aren't any) but not this one.

Comment: Edited to add a #undef